# Programming Language with Inflection

Tags: programming-languages

Is there a programming language that uses inflections (suffixing a word to add a certain meaning) instead of operators to express instructions? Just wondering.

What I am talking about is using inflections to add a meaning to an identifier such as a variable or type name.
For example:

```
native type integer

var x : integer = 12
var location : integers = 12, 5, 42
say 0th locationte to_string (( -te replaces "." operator. prints 12 ))
```

Comment: I always wondered what can programming languages borrwo from natural languages...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think [Perligata](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~damian/papers/HTML/Perligata.html) (Perl in Latin) is what you're looking for. :) From the article

> There is no reason why programming
>   languages could not also use
>   inflexions, rather than position, to
>   denote lexical roles.

Here's an example program (Sieve of Eratosthenes):

```
    #! /usr/local/bin/perl -w
    use Lingua::Romana::Perligata;
    maximum inquementum tum biguttam egresso scribe.
    meo maximo vestibulo perlegamentum da.
    da duo tum maximum conscribementa meis listis.
    dum listis decapitamentum damentum nexto
        fac sic
            nextum tum novumversum scribe egresso.
            lista sic hoc recidementum nextum cis vannementa da listis.
        cis.
```

Comment: This seems interesting, but for the sake of those not fluent in latin it would be cool to have a synopsis, or maybe some English comments.

Comment: A translation is right under the example at 

http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~damian/papers/HTML/Perligata.html#Putting_it_all_together_a_Gre

Answer (score 8):

This is partially facetious, but... assembly language? Things like conditional jump instructions are often variations on a root ("J" for jump or whatnot) with suffixes added to denote the associated condition ("JNZ" for jump-if-not-zero, et cetera).

Comment: That's a fair answer.  There are also the operand size suffixes of many assemblers.

Comment: For ARM assembly, even ordinary instructions can be made conditional by suffixes. E.g

ADD r0, r1, r2 ; sets r0 = r1 + r2

ADDEQ r0, r1, r2 ; sets r0 = r1 + r2 only if zero flag is set.

Answer (score 5):

The excellent (dare I say fascinating) game-design language [Inform 7](http://inform7.com/) is inflected like English.  But it's so closely integrated with a host of other design decisions that it's hard to peel away as a separate feature.

Anyone who is interested in language designs that are unusual but successful should check out Inform 7.

Comment: One specific example of Inform 7's inflections is in the relation syntax. You can define abstract relations between objects, such as a "love" relation between people, and then use syntax such as "if John is loving Marsha", which is different from "if John is loved by Marsha" or "if John has loved Marsha".

Answer (score 2):

Presumably any programming language that uses natural language explicitly or closely as a basis, e.g., [Natural-Language Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_programming). There was some research done at MIT into using English to produce high-level skeletons of programs, which is more in the realm of natural-language processing; the tool they created is called [Metafor](http://larifari.org/writing/IUI2005-Metafor.pdf).

As far as I know, no existing language has support for, say, modifying or extending keywords with inflection. Now you've got me interested, though, so I'm sure I'll come up with something soon!

Answer (score 0):

Of the 40 or so languages I know, the only thing that comes to mind is some rare SQL implementations which include friendly aliases.  For example to select a default database after connecting, the standard is `USE <some database name>` but one I used somewhere which also allowed `USING <some database name>`.

Answer (score 0):

- FORTRAN uses the first letter of the name to determine the type of an implicitly-declared variable.
- COBOL has singular and plural versions of its "figurative constants", e.g. `SPACE` and `SPACES`.

Answer (score 0):

Python3.7 standard module [contextvars](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/contextvars.html#module-contextvars) has Context Variables, which can be used for inflection..